# Git Merge Branch-Specific changes to other branch, ignoring merges

Tags: git, merge

I'm wondering if there's a good way to merge changes specific to a branch to another branch.

Lets say I have a master branch, with changes A,B,C,D and E.   I create a feature branch for feature 1 which splits off the master from B.  The feature branch has changes M, and N, and then is merged back with the master, such that it contains C' and D', and a then a new feature2 specific change O is added.
At the same time, another team creates another feature branch (feature2) split off of A, and makes changes X and Y.   What I'd like to do is merge the feature1 specific changes into the feature2 branch without grabbing any of the Branch1 specific changes (so, in the diagram below, I would want to merge changes M, N, and O to feature2, but I don't want B, C, D or E...

```
   A -- B -- C -- D -- E               (master)
    \    \         \ 
     \    M -- N -- (C'/D') -- O       (feature1)
      \                         \
       \                         \
        \-- X -- Y ------------  (M'/N'/O')     (feature2)
```

Now, in real life, the diagram is much more complex (there are several merges from master, and other branches into feature1).   Is there any way to grab only the commits that are specific to the feature1 branch and merge them onto feature2? (which will avoid conflicts when merging feature1 and feature2 back into master?)

Comment: Seems [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) IMHO
cherry-picking commit and apply in another branch will create conflict also. for example cherry-picking M and applying on Y can trigger a conflict. Why merging feature2 branch to master is triggering conflict ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by cherry-picking M, N, and O onto feature 2:

```sh
git switch feature2
git cherry-pick M N O
```

The resulting history will look like this. Note that M', N', and O' are on feature 2, but feature 2 wasn't merged with feature 1. There's no merge commit, and so there's no line between the branches.

```
   A -- B -- C -- D -- E               (master)
    \    \         \ 
     \    M -- N -- (C'/D') -- O       (feature1)
      \                         
       \                         
        \-- X -- Y -- M' -- N' -- O'   (feature2)
```

That being said, simply merging feature 1 into feature 2 is probably the best option, and it's okay if you get changes B, C, D, and O. This isn't any more likely to result in merge conflicts when you eventually merge back into master.

### When merge conflicts occur

Merge conflicts aren't magic. A merge conflict will only occur if two commits that are descendants of the merge base both change the same file in about the same location.

Let's look at your original repository structure again, before any merging:

```
   A -- B -- C -- D -- E               (master)
    \    \         \ 
     \    M -- N -- (C'/D') -- O       (feature1)
      \                         
       \                         
        \-- X -- Y                     (feature2)
```

The merge base of feature 2 and master is A, since that's the most recent commit that's on both feature 2 and master. You can ask git to tell you the merge base using [`git merge-base feature1 master`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base):

```sh
# Get commit hash
git merge-base feature2 master

# Get info about the commit that's the merge base
git log -n 1 $(git merge-base feature2 master)
```

Similarly, the merge base of feature 1 and master is D, since that's the most recent commit that's on both feature 1 and master.

When you merge feature1 into feature2, it now looks like this:

```
   A -- B -- C -- D -- E               (master)
    \    \         \ 
     \    M -- N -- (C'/D') -- O       (feature1)
      \                         \
       \                         \
        \-- X -- Y -------------- Z    (feature2)
```

Here, commit Z is a merge commit with parents O and Y.

Now, **the merge base for feature2 and master is D**. Because D was merged into feature1, and feature1 was merged into feature 2, D is the most recent commit that's on both master and feature 2.

The only way a merge conflict will occur is if occur when merging feature2 back into master is if E changes something that feature1 or feature2 changed. We don't have to worry about B, C, or D, because those are all integrated now.

## Merge conflicts aren't a bad thing

Merge conflicts aren't a bad thing. It just means that two people edited the same part of the same file on different branches. Shuffling commits around won't avoid them, and that's okay. The more mature a project becomes, and the more files it has, *the less likely you are to have a merge conflict*, because it's less likely multiple people will be working on the same file.

When they occur, resolve them (preferentially in an IDE that makes that easy, like VS Code), and move forward.